# Menu in actionbar not showing in next activity

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I am trying to duplicate the three dots menu in the actionbar to my other pages/activities. In my app I use buttons to navigatie to he next screen. I copied the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {                                                     
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
```

But nothing shows up in the next screen. I also tried adding items, standard it only has 'settings' but that doesn't work either. I imported the view.menu. The Actionbar itself with my appIcon does show. Making a new xml in the 'menu' folder as used in the code above, does not work.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ql"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.ql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.ql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCPlVHMostdkcJrs5YvkCXxHQaR94LrxEc"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.ContactActivity"  >


        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.MediaActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.CommunityActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.PersoonlijkActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.NieuwsActivity" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.PortalActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.StreamActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ql.GpsActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What activity are you extending? `Activity`, `FragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: I have 1 fragmentActivity for my googlemaps the rest are 'extends Activity'

Comment: ... and the device you're testing against is ICS at least? It matters because ActionBar by default is available since API level 11 upwards, but there is support in compatibility package for AB.

Comment: It is an HTC Desire X like 8 months old. android version 4.1

Comment: Ok, can you post also the Manifest.xml? Your application tag or the activity at least should have a theme set. It's important to see which one you have set.

Comment: I updated my post with the XML

Comment: Does `AppTheme` extends from `android:Theme.Holo` themese?

Comment: Updated my post with style.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a tutorial for googlemaps in a different project I migrated the working code into my other project, which is discussed up here. I tried the application and it still didn't work well, still no menu and still no different theme. Then I went to my 'build target' and I saw that the google playserverice 'is library' box was checked, I unchecked it and tried my application, And now it did work, different style and it showed the menu-items I added in the default menu.xml.

Thank you all for your awnsers

Answer (score 0):

Your style should use the holo style as base:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I updated to the 'Holo' theme, added the standard menu code with refers to menu.xml and imported view.menu. Nothing shows.

Comment: Please add your greatmenu.xml to your question.

Comment: Greatmenu is removed, was the same as the normal menu, I was testing wether I could add a menu and call for it in the mainpage but that didnt work either.

Comment: However you use in your frist code block "greatmenu" if you exchanged that by something else please update your question and add your actual menu file.

Comment: To make it simple: If you create the basic app with 1 activity there is a bar in the top with an icon and the three dots menu with 'settings' in it. If you wanted to add that to a new activity, how would you do that?

Comment: Updated the code from greatmenu to 'main' which is the standard xml